# Cannot connect to wired connection or see available networks

Tags: networking, upgrade, network-manager

I recently try to do a few updates and not I cannot connect to the network even though I have a ethernet connection. (I also cannot change display sizes but that's another issue)

Here is what I see when I type `$ ifconfig`

```
lo       Link encap: Local Loopback
         inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
         inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
         UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
         RX packets:608 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets: 608 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
         RX bytes: 45264 (45.2KB) TX bytes:45264 (45.2KB)
```

That's all I see. I don't see anything about et0. I also edited my /etc/network/interfaces and it now reads the following:

```
#interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8( and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface etho0 inet dhcp
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your eth0 interface is disabled. You should try to enable it using **ifup eth0**. The **ifconfig** only shows enabled interfaces. Good luck

Comment: It says `Cannot find device "etho"  Error getting hardware address for "eth0" No such device `

Comment: There are a couple suggestions here [Similar Question Ask Ubuntu Discussion](https://askubuntu.com/a/488247/587552)

Comment: use the "ip link" to show which interface you're using. Then configure on that interface. The error above means that you're using a different interface not eth0

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why the second to last line is about `eth0` and the last line is about `etho0` or is that just a typo?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you type `sudo service network-manager restart`? This just restarts the network-manager service. Changes to /etc/network/interfaces will not take place until the service is restarted if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I did try this and it doesn't seem to do anything.